# How to create a library to be imported instead of using switch statement in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new with this language (Objective-C). My purpose is to create an iOS app with randomized sentences. Everything is completed and right now i just randomizes words with the following code..

```
-(IBAction)randText:(id)sender {

    int text;
    text = rand()% 6;

    switch (text) {
        case 0:
            textLabel.text = @"Ett";
            break;
        case 1:
            textLabel.text = @"Två";
            break;
```

And so on...

But, I wonder if I can create like a library in a separate file and include/import that into  'switch' instead of making hundreds of 'cases' with longer sentences in each.

Hope you get what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a property list file that contains an array of strings. For example, create a plist file called `words.plist`, and then using Xcode's built in plist, editor set the root object to be an array, and add rows to the array. You can load it with:

```
NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"words" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];

// pick a random word:
NSString *randomWord = [words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(words.count)];
```

This has the following benefits:

1. The plist file is localisable, so that it can be translated into multiple languages without having to modify the code that loads the plist.
2. It's a good idea to try and keep data and code separate.
3. The list of words can be loaded from whatever URL you want, including from a web server.

As an example:

#### MyAppDelegate.h

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property NSArray *words;
// ... and your other properties as well
@end
```

#### MyAppDelegate.m

```
@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *) app
{
    NSURL *plistURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"words" withExtension:@"plist"];
    self.words = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];
}

- (NSString *) pickRandomWord
{
    return [self.words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(self.words.count)];
}

- (NSString *) makeRandomSentence
{
    NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        [result appendFormat:@"%@ ", [self pickRandomWord]];
    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: I got the list made, I just wonder where the code should be applied, I guess in the ".m"-file? And how does the URL-link work? Hate to be at the beginner stage and ask these kind of questions but I hope you can oversee that.

Comment: @user2060159: A "bundle" contains all of your programs resources. When you ask the bundle class for the URL to a resource it will return a URL like `file:///Applications/YourApp.app/Resources/words.plist`, you give this URL to the NSArray class for it to load. If you make `words` a property of your app delegate, you can load it in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method and use `self.words = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];`. Let me know if you need any explanations on anything.

Comment: Okey, so I do like this.. ' NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:file:///Applications/YourApp.app/Resources/words.plist]; ' But with my own URL. And then ' @property NSString *words; ' as property. Then use the ' self.words.. ' line with the URL in delegate.m?

Comment: @user2060159: I've edited my answer to illustrate what I mean. Don't hard-code the URL, always ask the bundle for it. The bundle does all the work and ensures that your program will be compatible with future OS and framework releases.

Comment: I made it simple and copied your code. Though i'm too untutored to understand what I need to change in the code. ON..  'return [self.words objectAtIndex:arc4random_uniform([self.words.count])];'  It sais "expected identifier" on the last but one square bracket.

Comment: @user2060159: Oops pardon me, I am typing this from the top of my head so it is untested. To get the number of items in an array you can use `self.items.count` **or** the old-school way `[[self words] count]` and I accidentally used a mix of the two! I've updated my answer.

Comment: Okey, no-problem. Everywhere you written plistURL i guess I should overwrite with the actual URL? On which places should I overwrite with my own "value" or what to call it? Very appreciated help I must say, you seem to know this very well (unlike me).

Comment: @user2060159: Don't replace `plistURL` with a full URL, you should always get the URL from the `NSBundle` method. You shouldn't need to write the full URL anywhere. Check out [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH1-SW1) about resource programming. In this case I used URLs instead of pathnames because URLs are capable of representing files not just on the device but anywhere on the web, so they are often more useful/flexible to work with than paths.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the words into an array and use arc4random_uniform to pick an index in the array. You don't need any switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all strings in an NSArray and then get a random object using

```
arrayWithStrings[arc4random_uniform(arrayWithStrings.count)];
```

If you have all your strings in a JSON or plist file, you can load that through `NSJSONSerialization` or `[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:]`